# PHP range for hebrew alphabets

Tags: php, range

PHP has a function range('a','z') which prints the English alphabet a, b, c, d, etc. 
Is there a similar function for hebrew alphabets?

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
function utfOrd($c) {       
    return intval(array_pop(unpack('H*', $c)),16);      
}

function utfChr($c) {
return pack('H*', base_convert("$c", 10, 16));
}

var_dump(array_map('utfChr', range(utfOrd('א'), utfOrd('ת'))));
```

Prints:

```
array
  0 => string 'א' (length=2)
  1 => string 'ב' (length=2)
  2 => string 'ג' (length=2)
  3 => string 'ד' (length=2)
  4 => string 'ה' (length=2)
  5 => string 'ו' (length=2)
  6 => string 'ז' (length=2)
  7 => string 'ח' (length=2)
  8 => string 'ט' (length=2)
  9 => string 'י' (length=2)
  10 => string 'ך' (length=2)
  11 => string 'כ' (length=2)
  12 => string 'ל' (length=2)
  13 => string 'ם' (length=2)
  14 => string 'מ' (length=2)
  15 => string 'ן' (length=2)
  16 => string 'נ' (length=2)
  17 => string 'ס' (length=2)
  18 => string 'ע' (length=2)
  19 => string 'ף' (length=2)
  20 => string 'פ' (length=2)
  21 => string 'ץ' (length=2)
  22 => string 'צ' (length=2)
  23 => string 'ק' (length=2)
  24 => string 'ר' (length=2)
  25 => string 'ש' (length=2)
  26 => string 'ת' (length=2)
```

If you need some more characters, you can use this to create your hardcoded array or merge few ranges.

Comment: +1 for actually doing the code. Just remember to use UTF-16 when echoing to a browser

Comment: This is a great function. I wonder if it can work for actually transforming numbers ( eg - "12" == "יב" )

Answer (score 3):

Range can work with the standard western alphabet because the characters A thru Z are consecutive values in the ASCII (and UTF-8) character set.

Hebrew characters are not ASCII chars (see [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML_for_the_Hebrew_alphabet)) but you could set an initial range of the UTF-8 numeric values and then just array_map that to characters.